# Using ng-repeat across two containers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an application that has two boxes. On the left div it will display a list of clickable links, once clicked it will display that links information on the div to the right. I've managed to get my data to hide and show when the link is clicked but only within the same div. What's the best appraoch when it comes to doing this with Angular?

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="faqController">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="guide-section">
        <h1>Select a Topic</h1>
        <ul ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
          <li><a href="#" ng-click="showData=!showData">{{ faq.title }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="guide-section">
      <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
      <h1>{{ faq.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ faq.info }}</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
   var myApp = angular.module('supportApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.controller('faqController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showData = true;

    $http.get('data/faq.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.faqs = data;
      //console.log(data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //Complete error fallback
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add to your second div `ng-show='showdata'` - another option would be to show if $scope.showFaq is populated, which would eliminate dealing with another variable

Also, you `ng-repeat` should be in your `li` not `ul` - `ng-repeat` should be on the element you want to repeat (unlike most for loops in other languages)

Once you populate the $scope.faqs, the list will show with the links.

Once you click the selected faq, it is used to populate the $scope.showFaq and $scope.showData is set to true...

```js
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showData = false;
    
    $scope.showHide = function(faq) {
      $scope.showData = true;
      $scope.showFaq = faq;
    };

    $scope.faqs = [
      {'title': 'title 1', 'info': 'info 1'},
      {'title': 'title 2', 'info': 'info 2'}
    ];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="guide-section">
        <h1>Select a Topic</h1>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="faq in faqs"><a ng-click="showHide(faq)">{{ faq.title }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="guide-section" ng-show="showData">
      <h1>{{ showFaq.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ showFaq.info }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this works, the second column is where I want the data to display, I'm having problems toggling it between several divs because I'm repeating it from a different column. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - voila! does it make sense?

Comment: Just read your edit. Saved my life! Still quite new to Angular and this threw me off for some reason. Thanks man!